# Validate a selector input for a value other than first PHP

Tags: php, html

Sorry, I know I asked this yesterday, but the answer I got was for Javascript, which worked for me, but now I am writing the PHP script and I can't figure out the PHP Version either. I tried to research it, but nothing came up.

I am trying to create a validation script for a few selectors such as month, day, and year for your birthday. Basically I want the script to run as:

IF the selector is on the first option return false ELSE return true

What is the IF statement I need in order to return the script false if the first option in the list is selected.

For example,

```
<select>
    <option>FAIL IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    <option>PASS IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    <option>PASS IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    ...And So On
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <select name="test" id="test">
        <option value="0">FAIL IF ...</option>
        <option value="1">PASS IF ...</option>
        <option value="2">PASS IF ...</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**PHP inside some validate function (form.php)**

```
if($_POST['test'] == "0") return false;
else return true;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a variable instead of the name of the selector?

Comment: What do you mean? The name selector is how you generate the `$_POST` array index. You can, of course, do something like this: `$new_var = $_POST['test']`

Answer (score 0):

You can supply `value` attribute inside each `option` tag

```
<select>
    <option value="">FAIL IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    <option value="something">PASS IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    <option value="something else">PASS IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    ...And So On
</select>
```

Then check the value of the `<select>` tag by using

```
if($_POST['name of select tag'] == '') // first selector is chosen
{
   // display the error message
}
```